# How get a URL from EditText to play a radio stream?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, streaming

I want to play a radio for example from here: "http://legacy.scahw.com.au/3rmr_32". and I want to get it from an EditText that the user should enter it.

When I put the url directly to a string it works but when I write it to an EditText and pass it to a string, it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me where is the problem?

### MainActivity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        final String urlString = url.getText().toString();

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startPlaying(urlString);
            }
        });

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
            }
        });



        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {  
            player.setDataSource(urlString);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPlaying(String sp) {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {  
            player.setDataSource(urlString);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

### Main.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:hint="Enter URL"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="paly"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStopPlay"
    android:text="stop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonPlay"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using final String urlString = url.getText().toString();
So string will contain blank and will not change in future when you type in it.
In place of final variable please use url.getText().toString() directly to pass value.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
final String urlString = url.getText().toString();
```

you should write in onClickListene, as show below

```
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String urlString = url.getText().toString();
        startPlaying(urlString);
    }
});
```

may this will help you, all the best

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
final String urlString = url.getText().toString();
```

with this:

```
final String urlString = URLEncoder.encode(url.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```